# TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined any solution?

Tags: reactjs

```
function RenderLeader({leader}){
    return(
        <div className="col-12 mt-5" key={leader.id}>
            <Media tag="li">
                <Media left middle>
                    <Media object src={leader.image} alt={leader.name}/>
                </Media>
                <Media body>
                    <Media heading>{leader.name}</Media>
                    <p>{leader.designation}</p>
                    <p>{leader.description}</p>
                </Media>
            </Media>
        </div>
    );
}

function About(props) {

    const leaders = props.leaders.map((detailsOfLeader) => {
        return(
                <RenderLeader key={detailsOfLeader.id} leader={detailsOfLeader}/>
        );
    });

    return(
        <div className="container">
            <div className="row">
                <Breadcrumb>
                    <BreadcrumbItem><Link to="/home">Home</Link></BreadcrumbItem>
                    <BreadcrumbItem active>About Us</BreadcrumbItem>
                </Breadcrumb>
                <div className="col-12">
                    <h3>About Us</h3>
```

Comment: Welcome, please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your post accordingly. Right now we can't really understand much.

Answer (score 0):

I think the leaders array is object or null, thats why you can't map
If the leaders is null just write `props.leaders && props.leaders.map`